# Creating design using css

Tags: css, react-native

How can i create this design for my react-native view component background using only css (style)?

i want the view 2 to have green background with a little curve on top that meets the top right in the center.

using just borderRadius did not help. the height and width from the top corners being cut off is not same in the diagram. using borderRadius reduces same amount of height and width from corner that does not product the below background.

[image]

Comment: This type of question has been asked a lot of times here, and the answer is either using SVG or Images and there's no CSS for this.

Comment: if you are talking about react-native, it's not real css but only a simulated one. I think you have to make an image for this.

Comment: Refer  this link https://github.com/arunkumarrmrj/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 0):

I used `border-radius: 70%/100px 100px 0 0;` to attain similar type of curve in your figure.
Here is my full code:

```css
#white {
  background-color: white;
}

#view1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#view2 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#text1,
#text2 {
  padding-top: 42px;
}

#round {
  background-color: green;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 0px;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 70%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="white">
    <div id="view1">
      <div id="text1">
        View 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="view2">
      <div id="round">
        <div id="text2">
          VIEW 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5be5regh/) to fiddle
Hope you got your answer!Thanks.